# REST API ArrayList @DELETE

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class BookList {

    public static List<Book> Listing= new ArrayList<Book>();

    Book book = new Book();

    public List<Book> getBooks(){
        Book book1=new Book("1", "Name 1","Author 1", "Text");
        Book book2=new Book("2", "Name 2","Author 2", "Text");
        Book book3=new Book("3",  "Name 3","Author 3", "Text");
        Book book4=new Book("4", "Name 4","Author 4", "Text");


        Listing.add(book1);
        Listing.add(book2);
        Listing.add(book3);
        Listing.add(book4);

        return Listing;

    }
```

And I have a Main Java Class where @DELETE function is located.

```
@DELETE
    @Path("/{bookID}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response deleteBook(@PathParam("bookiD") int id){
        String output = (bookList.getBook(id));
        return Response.status(200).entity("Hehehe").build(); 
    }
```

What I want to get is to when I run this @DELETE in Postman is to provide me back with the list of books that are left in the list and exluclude the one that book which ID I put into link: For example localhost:49000/1 - removes book with ID 1 from the list and return back the rest of the books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a simple `ArrayList` delete issue

Like your `getBook` method, add a `deleteBook` method and then implement the method that removes book from your list.  `list.remove(getBook(id-1)); //

Then in your `public Response deleteBookXML(@PathParam("bookID") int id)` method, first `deleteBook`, and instead of returning Response with *laughing buddha*  (`entity("Hehehe")`), as Entity, use bookList as entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
BookList.list.removeif(x -> x.id.equals(id + "");
return Response.status(200).entity(BookList.list).build();
```

It appeares that your Book object is using Strings as ids?

The above code will use your static list of books and remove a book element with the id equal to the id from the URL.

The code will then return http status 200 with the list of books as entity.